# Is {0} a subgroup of the reals under multiplication?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

As {0} by itself is a group under multiplication, with 0 as its own inverse and is associative, and 0 is also a subset of $\Bbb{R}$ under multiplication, then {0} is a subgroup. However, {0} and $\Bbb{R}$ do not share the same identity element (the proof that the identity elements are equivalent entails division by zero). So Is {0} a subgroup of the integers under multiplication?

Comment: No, it's not a subgroup, for precisely the reason you identified that they don't share an identity.

Comment: The integers under multiplication are not a group.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan My book proves that as a collorary to being a subgroup by first proving that $e^2_s=e_se_g$ then dividing, which is not valid because $e_s=0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas My question still applies under $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: @VladimirLenin: $\mathbb{R}$ is not a group with multiplication. $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ is, though.

Comment: @AlexWertheim thanks for the explanation, can't believe I missed that.

Comment: @AlexWertheim, can you please post it as an answer?